I can't run the spring mvc application with vaadin 23
I have an application on spring mvc, I want to add vaadin to it so that it opens along the path /example/vaadin. But when I start, I get this error
HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileHandler.serveStaticResource(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)" because "this.staticFileHandler" is null`
At the same time, in the org.eclipse server configuration.jetty.server.Server, adding a new servlet

I have a configuration for jetty org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server for
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">                                                 
   <property name="name" value="vaadinServlet"/>                                                 
   <property name="servlet">                                                     
     <bean class="com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet"/>                                                 
   </property>                                             
</bean>

for servlets and mapping
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
   <property name="servletName" value="vaadinServlet"/>
   <property name="pathSpec" value="/example/*"/>
</bean>

and this ui
@Route("vaadin")
@PageTitle("example")
public class PromoPage extends VerticalLayout {

    public PromoPage() {
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
        add(new Label("Hi!"));
        Button button = new Button("create");
        button.addClickListener((ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>) event ->
                Notification.show("uhh, created"));
        setMargin(true);
        add(button);
    }
}

The documentation says to use Spring Servlet, but it is not in the vaadin version 23 here. I don't know what to do, do you have any ideas?

What do you mean by "The documentation says to use Spring Servlet, but it is not in the vaadin version 23 here."
